# Oxidation of dihydropyridine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image]

This is a step in a experiment I have carried out. Usually DDQ (dichlorodicyanoquinone) would be used here to oxidise the dihydropyridine. However in this case Nitric Acid is being used as the oxidising agent. I'm unsure as to how this would happen mechanistically, my initial guess that since the product is aromatic and Nitrogen can help expel the hydrogen atom from the 4 position this will happen quite fast in one step. What role will the Nitric Acid have in this reaction? Mechanistic detail would be helpful, I can't find an example of this in any textbook.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question on the mechanism, but did you consider to perform the oxidation of your Hantzsch DHPs with nitrite in methylene chloride using acidified silica (add silica to hydrochloric acid, stirr and evaporate) as a solid support?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha No, this is a reaction I performed in an undergrad lab. Simply dissolved the DHP in glacial acetic acid and added sodium nitrite drop wise, and left to stir for an hour. It specifically says not to worry about mechanistic detail in the procedure but I was curious how this step happened.

Comment: Did you mean nitrous acid? Not that I know the mechanism. Loss of H2 via an ionic mechanism has to involve a proton transfer and a hydride transfer to somewhere. The proton transfer isn't a big deal and under acidic conditions you might even get the pyridinium cation instead. In any case it's going to be some kind of hydride transfer to HNO2. Exactly where I don't know. Edit: Actually, I have a better idea. HNO2 isn't going to hang around, it's probably going to decompose to give water and $\ce{NO+}$. Now that's a suitable electrophile for "$\ce{H-}$" to attack.

Comment: @orthocresol Yes that does explain why it wasn't done in an ice bath either, keeping it cold would prevent it decomposing as much into NO+ but since it's basically done at room temp (advised to keep under 50 degrees) it's probably to ensure the NO+ electrophile is generated, so i presume the mechanism would work just like the one with DDQ but the hydrogen pushed towards the NO+ instead. I mentioned Nitric Acid because that's what Clayden said was the oxidising agent.

Comment: A quick Google search tells me that both HNO2 and HNO3 can be used as oxidising agents (really, a lot of things work, because there is a strong driving force for the oxidation of a dihydropyridine - namely aromaticity). Hydride transfer to NO+ gives you a very weird HNO species, I'd suspect that would decompose to give H2O + N2O, but again as far as I'm concerned all bets are off.

Comment: Again, this doesn't answer your question, but Arthur Hantzsch himself described in *Ann. Chem.*, **1882**, *215*, 1-82 that - even under cooling - dropwise addition of nitric acid to a dihydropyridine, which he called "Hydrocollidindicarbonsäureather", led to a vigorous reaction in which a large amount of the starting material was destroyed. With nitrous acid, on the other hand, the oxidation was smooth.